# Загрузка нескольких страниц в один WebBrowser

Tags: c#

Можно ли в webbrowser отобразить несколько интернет страничек одновременно?
Страница1, за ней страница2 и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем так сложно? Но вообще можно через фреймы наверное, как то так:

```
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.DocumentText ="<html><head></head><frameset rows=\"80,*\" cols=\"*\">"+
                    "<frame src=\""+firstUrl+"\" name=\"firstFrame\" scrolling=\"no\" noresize>"+
                    "<frame src=\""+secondUrl+"\" name=\"secondFrame\" scrolling=\"no\" noresize></frameset></html>"
```